# Limit maximum requests / second for a specific path on HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, rate-limiting

I'm trying to achieve this scenario :

On a specific path only, I receive a steady 9 requests/sec on the frontend. Everything is fine, use the regular Backend.
I now receive 11 req/s, I want to reject any requests above 10. But still want to continue replying to a maximum of 10 req/sec.

Everything I have found and tried implementing (like this : https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/12/haproxy-http-header-rate-limiting/), are black or white solution, it drops everything once the rate is reached. So it's a protection against DDOS, abuser, but not a real rate limiting solution.

Is there any way to achieve that ?
PS: using HAproxy 1.5.8

Comment: Have you tried maxconnrate? http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#3.2-maxconnrate

Comment: Or by using `rate-limit sessions <rate>` ([docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#rate-limit)) in the frontend.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add an important requirement, I need to limit just a specific path, not frontend wide. `maxconnrate` is a global setting and wouldn't work for me.`rate-limit sessions` does what I want but is frontend-wide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `rate-limit sessions`, is the following feasible for you?

```
frontend http_in
   bind 0.0.0.0:80
   acl is_path url_beg /path/example/
   use_backend forwarder if is_path

backend forwarder
   server localhost 127.0.0.1:4444 send-proxy

frontend limit_path_backend
   bind 127.0.0.1:4444 accept-proxy
   rate-limit sessions 10
   default_backend webnodes
```

Comment: Was about to post it, I got the same solution from the mailing list and confirmed by Willy that it's the recommended way. Note that the last frontend can be a "listen" with the server directly declared in it (instead of having another frontend + backend).